# What's the difference between open-source QRNG and Quantis Device?

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, classical-computing

qRNG is an open-source quantum random number generator written in python and Quantis RNG is a physical quantum random number generator. Both are capable of generating quantum random numbers, but how do they differ?

Comment: Unless the python code is in turn running something on a physical quantum device it cannot be quantum randomness.

Answer (score 1):

qRNG python module and Quantis RNG both exploits quantum randomness, but they are based on different quantum properties. Quantis is based on photon polarization, whereas qRNG uses quantum computer based on superconducting qubits.

Quantis RNG is a standalone hardware wich delivers random numbers, so you don't need third party system or internet connection, while qRNG needs to execute code on remote quantum computer, wich could take time and need an available service. Quantis RNG has certification, wich certify the randomness. I expect that the bit rate is higher with Quantis RNG.